# Using lists to retrieve information from MySql Database getting Exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: c#, mysql, list, phpmyadmin, datareader

I have this C# code:

```
    public static Member searchMember(int memberID)
    {
        Member member = null; ;
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM MEMBER WHERE memberID='" + memberID + "'";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);

        try
        {
           connection.Open();
           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

           // Create a data reader and Execute the command
           dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           //Read the data and store them in the list
           while (dataReader.Read())
           {
              member = new Member();
              member.MemberID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]);
              member.UserName = dataReader[1].ToString();
              member.Password = dataReader[2].ToString();
              member.Name = dataReader[3].ToString();
              member.Surname = dataReader[4].ToString();
              member.MF1 = dataReader[5].ToString();
              member.DOB1 = dataReader[6].ToString();
              member.Address = dataReader[7].ToString();
              member.PhoneNo = dataReader[8].ToString();
              member.EMail = dataReader[9].ToString();
           }

           //return list to be displayed
           return member;
        }

        catch(Exception)
        {
           throw;
        }

        finally
        {
           //close Data Reader
           dataReader.Close();

           //close Connection
           connection.Close();
        }
     }
```

What this method do is that it retrieves data from a mysql database table and stores it in a list. For some reason when this method is begin executed I'm receiving an exception with details: "Index was outside the bounds of the array.". I don't know if I provided enough information but please request any other information if you don't have enough.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the structure of `Member` table?

Comment: What do you mean the columns that I have in my table?

Comment: Yes - your select could be returning less than 10 columns ... I would also recommend rather than using `SELECT * ...` to specify each column  you need individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `dataReader` doesn't have as much value as your code use. Are you sure you have 10 columns in your table `Member` ?

Comment: No, I don't... -.- (stupid me)  Thanks for solving my problem @Kabulan0lak :)

Comment: NP. @Milen Pavlov is right, you should specify the column you want in your `SELECT` like `SELECT id, name, username` instead of `SELECT *`. Your code will be clearer and you won't have those type of errors again.

Comment: What I did is I made a class called Person, Class Member inherits from class person. In mysql I did a table for person and member. I wish to retrieve the value of both tables and store them in a single list. Is there a possible way to do it?

Comment: You can write a query that makes a union between your two tables : `SELECT name, username FROM Member
UNION
SELECT name, username FROM Person
`
All you need is selecting the same attributes in your tables

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using index numbers, when refering to database columns. When the structure or order of the table changes, your indexes may refer to wrong columns. Use the column names instead:

```
dataReader["DbColumnName"].ToString();
```

You should also avoid using the "*"-query. Define each column you want to get:

```
"SELECT memberID, userName FROM MEMBER WHERE memberID='" + memberID + "'";
```

Check that your database table contains all 10 columns. You're maybe trying to read a column that doesn't exists in the database.